Groups of three words that appear to be an adjective, its comparative, and its superlative -- but aren't
I apologize in advance if this doesn't belong here. Not sure which SE is the best fit.
I've come across three groups of words that are formed like an adjective, its comparative, and its superlative, but aren't --
Temp, temper, tempest
Hone, honer, honest
Dive, diver, divest
-- and am wondering if anyone can think of any other examples of this.

Try https://english.stackexchange.com/

@Benjamin Wang - I considered that one, but most of the posts there are about English  usage.

I feel like there was a [wordplay] puzzle here with a similar premise…

Earn, earner, earnest

@xnor - That works!

@Someone maybe this one

I’m voting to close this question because it is a "big list" question with a number of answers only limited by how far people are willing to stretch their definition of an English word. Questions which could keep accruing answers without any clear "best" or way to judge between them, are not appropriate for this site. Try chat.

@Someone You're probably thinking of this one by Ankoganit. However, the premise here is that only 2 of the 3 were real and the other fake...

Yeah, that was the puzzle.

Bee, beer, beest if you're okay getting a little archaic
